# How do I enable package encxvlna?

Tags: installing, languages, fmtutil

Encxvlna is a package that inserts non-breaking space into Czech documents. However, it does not seem to work with texlive-2009-11 (the version in Ubuntu Natty). There is a manual describing its usage here: http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/generic/encxvlna/encxvlna.pdf .

I am using utf8 encoding in my documents (i.e. \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ).

If I understand the manual correctly, I should modify files in /etc/texmf/fmt.d directory as follows:

10texlive-base.cnf should be

```
# 10texlive-base.cnf
# You can change/add entries to this file and changes will be preserved
# over upgrades, even if you have removed the main package prior
# (not if you purged it). You should leave the following pseudo comment
# present in the file!
# -_- DebPkgProvidedMaps -_-
# 
etex pdftex language.def -translate-file=cp227.tcx *etex.ini
pdfetex pdftex language.def -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini
luatex luatex language.def luatex.ini
dviluatex luatex language.def dviluatex.ini
pdftex pdftex - -enc cslatex-utf8.ini
mf mf-nowin - -translate-file=cp227.tcx mf.ini
tex tex - tex.ini
```

10texlive-latex-base.cnf should be

```
# 10texlive-latex-base.cnf
# You can change/add entries to this file and changes will be preserved
# over upgrades, even if you have removed the main package prior
# (not if you purged it). You should leave the following pseudo comment
# present in the file!
# -_- DebPkgProvidedMaps -_-
# 
latex pdftex language.dat -enc cslatex-utf8.ini
dvilualatex luatex language.dat dvilualatex.ini
lualatex luatex language.dat lualatex.ini
pdflatex pdftex language.dat -enc  cslatex-utf8.ini
```

I am not sure if I need to modify 10texlive-lang-czechoslovak.cnf if I am using babel for Czech support, but it shoud do no harm but:

```
# 10texlive-lang-czechslovak.cnf
# You can change/add entries to this file and changes will be preserved
# over upgrades, even if you have removed the main package prior
# (not if you purged it). You should leave the following pseudo comment
# present in the file!
# -_- DebPkgProvidedMaps -_-
# 
csplain         pdftex         -       -etex -enc csplain-utf8.ini
pdfcsplain      pdftex         -       -etex -enc csplain-utf8.ini
cslatex         pdftex         -       -etex -enc cslatex-utf8.ini
pdfcslatex      pdftex         -       -etex -enc cslatex-utf8.ini
```

Then, I should apply my changes with:

```
sudo update-fmtutil
sudo dpkg-reconfigure texlive-base
```

But then even a minimal document such as this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{encxvlna} 
\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

Triggers following error message:

```
! Package encxvlna Error: encTeX of Feb 2003 or later not detected,
(encxvlna) the rest of the package will be ignored.
See the encxvlna package documentation for explanation.
Type H return for immediate help.
...
l.40 }
% Package error message
This package is implemented by new primitives of encTeX of Feb 2003
but this extension was not detected in your system. You can continue
but all commands of `encxvlna' will be ignored. If your TeX distribution
contains encTeX but does not activate it, you have to create the format
using the -enc switch (e.g. in fmtutils.cnf). If you do not have encTeX
at all, you have to compile it from the source code. You can find
the source code including documentation at
http://math.feld.cvut.cz/olsak/enctex.html
```

But it is not clear to me what to do with it. According to this mailing-list [post](http://www.linux.cz/pipermail/texlive/2011-January/000057.html), it seems to be broken, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: There is also more wordy czech wiki page that I based my steps on 
[here](http://goo.gl/FMCxp) - I have low reputation so I could not add it to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't change the entries in `10texlive-base.cnf` and `10texlive-latex-base.cnf`, which define the behavior of the standard tools pdftex, latex, and pdflatex.

The changes in `10texlive-lang-czechslovak.cnf` don't seem good: I would try

```
csplain    pdftex - -output-format=dvi -enc *csplain-utf8.ini
pdfcsplain pdftex - -output-format=pdf -enc *csplain-utf8.ini
cslatex    pdftex - -output-format=dvi -enc *cslatex-utf8.ini
pdfcslatex pdftex - -output-format=pdf -enc *cslatex-utf8.ini
```

If all goes well, you can compile with `pdfcslatex`

Comment: Tried but it does not work. It gives the same erorr as before. I suspect that it is a bug in latex but I have no idea where to report it or to whom.

Comment: Actually, I found out that instead of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure texlive-base`, I need to run `sudo fmtutil --all` and it works all-right.

Comment: Please, how to configure it for xelatex?

Comment: @pevik I don't think you can enable encTeX for XeTeX